# What does Apple mean by term "registers" in regards to creating new tableView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working through an exercise which uses tableviews.  I noticed within a test during the exercise, they use a method I haven't needed in the past when implementing tableviews from storyboards.  The method is:

```
func register(AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)
```

After reading the short description of this function in the reference pages.  I'm curious to know what does apple mean by term "registers"?  I half assume that since we are doing this exercise programmatically at the moment, this function is only needed if you're creating UITableviews programmatically.  If this statement is incorrect, please let me know as I'd like to learn more.

Here is the code from the example:

```
func test_CellForRow_DequesCellFromTableView(){

        let mockTableView = MockTableView()

        mockTableView.dataSource = sut

        mockTableView.delegate = sut

        mockTableView.register(ItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")

        sut?.itemManger?.add(ToDoItem.init(title: "Foo"))

        mockTableView.reloadData()

        _ = mockTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0))

        XCTAssertTrue(mockTableView.cellGotDequeed)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DequeueReusable` methods are there to check if any reusable cells are left before creating new ones. Hope you have an idea about the working of reusable cells

What happens when the queue is empty? Now we do need to create a cell. We can follow 2 methods to create a cell,

1. Create cell manually
2. Create it automatically by registering cell with a valid xib file

**METHOD 1**

if you do it with manually, you must check cell is empty or not after dequeueReusableCell check. Just like below,

```
// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Reuse an old cell if exist else return nil
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    //check cell is nil if nil you want to allocate it with proper cell
    if(cell == nil){
        //create cell manually
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")

    }

    // do stuff to the cell here

  return cell
  }
```

**METHOD 2**

We could create the cell manually like above which is totally fine. But it would be convenient if the table view would create the cell for us directly.

That way we don't have to load it from a nib or instantiate it.
For registering a cell with a xib or class we use `func register(AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)` method. Let see an example,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

// ...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as MyCell
    // no "if" - the cell is guaranteed to exist
    // ... do stuff to the cell here ...
    cell.textLabel.text = // ... whatever
    // ...
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are "registering" your custom Cell class - ItemCell - for reuse as a cell for your tableview.

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register

Answer (score 1):

"Register" tells XCode that the cell exists. A cell is registered under a "reuse identifier." This is a unique string that corresponds to your TableViewCell, in this case ItemCell.

A cell can also be registered in the Storyboard by filling out the "Identifier" in the cell's attributes inspector.

[image]